# Discrete optimization - selecting exactly N items from each row and column of a score matrix

Tags: python, search, computation-theory, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Given a matrix of scores, I'd like to select exactly n elements from each column and each row such that the total score of the selected elements across the entire matrix will be as high as possible.

Example: given the cost matrix

```
array([[0.65500799, 0.79214695, 0.39854742],
       [0.53634974, 0.3682463 , 0.99663978],
       [0.73423119, 0.87150676, 0.80823699]])
```

The optimal selection for n=1 is:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

the total score of this solution is 0.65500799+0.87150676+0.99663978

The optimal selection for n=2 is:

```
array([[1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1.]])
```

the total score of this solution is 0.65500799+0.53634974+0.79214695+0.87150676+0.99663978+0.80823699

These solutions were obtained by a naive [Breadth-First Search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). However, this approach isn't computationally feasible (run time explodes) for larger problems (e.g., 10x10, n=2).

Questions:

1. How is this discrete optimization problem classified?
2. What heuristics can allow finding good solutions for this problem quickly?
3. What Python libararies implement these heuristics?

Comment: Try at https://stats.stackexchange.com/, maybe they got some ideas.

Comment: This can be formulated as an integer programming problem and solved quickly using off the shelf IP solvers. If you are open to this approach, I can provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on integer programming (IP).

*Decision variables:* `x[i,j] = 1` if we select the item in row `i`, column `j`.

*Parameters (inputs):* `s[i,j] =` score for entry (`i`, `j`)

*Formulation:*

```
maximize sum {i, j} s[i,j] * x[i,j]
subject to sum {i} x[i,j] = n     for all j
           sum {j} x[i,j] = n     for all i
           x[i,j] in {0,1}        for all i, j
```

You can implement this in Python/`PuLP` or a solver-specific package such as `gurobipy` or `docplex`. I would expect that these solvers can solve even moderately large instances of the problem, to optimality (not heuristically), within a fraction of a second.

Comment: Following your answer, I found a docplex example code for a very similar problem - https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/boxes.ipynb - works like a charm.